# using print_r to print image path, instead of image itself

Tags: php

Ok more details:

Line with print_r outputs rendered images because in database
they are stored like `<img src="" etc..`

I want to see the path not image.

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($rows as $row){
    if ($row->fulltext != ''){

        print_r ( $row->fulltext );
        echo "\n";

    }

}


echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: You only get images of you put the url inside an img tag. Just posting a url is posting a string, there is no magic in that.

Comment: that gives me blank page.

Comment: Your vague description of what happens isn't sufficient to get a factual answer. Post some actual code and output excerpts.

Answer (score 0):

Render image in browser:

```
$img = // get image path
echo '<img src='.$img.' />';
```

Output image path in browser:

```
$img = // get image path
echo $img;
```